# Change div class position which return from servlet class

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, html

I have a single HTML file which contains several div elements. In second div element, I have a registration form where on submit request goes to servlet class and store value in database and return back HTML file. But first div element is open and I want after successfully return from servlet class second div element registration from open.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Maybe it's not stupid, but you should try harder with your grammar, sorry. It's hard to read it.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('div2').style.display='block';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just let JSP generate the HTML accordingly with help of [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). You only need to transform the HTML file to a JSP file if necessary by changing `.html` extension to `.jsp` extension, or by adding a JSP servlet mapping on `*.html` in `web.xml`.

The JSP/JSTL code would look like this

```html
<c:if test="${success}">
    <div>This will be displayed only when ${success} evaluates true.</div>
</c:if>
```

with in servlet

```
if (success) {
    request.setAttribute("success", true);
}
```

Note that this is a rather basic example. If your servlet happen to already have set something as a request or session attribute which indicates a successful submit, such as placing the registered and logged-in user in the session scope by

```
session.setAttribute("user", user);
```

then you could perform the conditional check in JSTL as follows:

```html
<c:if test="${not empty user}">
    <div>This will be displayed only when ${user} is present in the scope.</div>
</c:if>
```

You can by the way also use a `<c:choose>` instead if you have multiple conditions.